# Who is this Marvel female character from an "Avenge the Fallen" poster?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification

Who is this woman? She appears on the Marvel "Avenge the Fallen" poster below.

[image: The poster showing the woman's face]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's Hope Van Dyne, the Wasp, played by Evangeline Lily. As part of the ending events of *Avengers: Infinity War* and shown in the post credits scene in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*

> she was decimated, so she is one of the ones to be avenged.

Comment: Who killed her?

Comment: @Wolfie lol, “This is all I want to know. Nothing else.”...”Who killed her?” FWIW, I had to go back a couple of times to work out who it was, I thought she looks like Margaery from GoT.

Comment: @Wolfie If you want an answer to that question you need to watch Avengers: Infinity War.

Comment: ...might try watching the films @Wolfie ;)

Comment: if only her character had been decimated from the Hobbit films...